# Matlab to Python: Solving the system using SVD

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, svd

I am trying to convert Matlab code to Python code.

I am stuck with

```
x = A\b;
```

where `A` is 2D array `(2257x456)` and where `b` is 1D array `(2257x1)`.

The array outputed in Matlab `x` is 1D array `(456x1)`

Also there is a comment in Matlab code which says: `%Solve the system using SVD`

So how can I do this in Python?

I try with following code's but with no success.

```
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, b.T)[1].T
x = A :\\ b # found this [here][1]
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)


[1]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html
```

Update:

Error and result produced:

```
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b) : LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

x = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b) : x is not expected result, it is 3D array (4x456x1)

x = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, b.T)[1].T : LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions
```

Comment: *"... with no success."*  Explain the problem that you encountered.  Did you get an error?  If so, show the error message.  Did you get a result that you didn't expect?  If so, show what you got and explain what you expected.  (It might be simpler to test the code with smaller arrays, e.g. A might be 10x5 and b 10x1.)

Comment: Updated question, I don't really understand the math behind the operation in Matlab so I am just trying out codes and checking if output array ('x') is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)`.  Take another look at the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html), and note that it returns *four* values.  So to use it, you would write

```
x, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
```

Or, if you want to ignore everything except `x`,

```
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but the result is not the same as in Matlab. I guess 'x' is not calculated same as in Matlab with lstsq() function? Note that A and b are identical in Python and Matlab